# Find the last character(s) from computername in batch

Tags: batch

Our computer names have different format like

```
AB-11-123-X and 
WCC123457VW
```

If using  `%computername:~0,2%`  can find the first two characters. What will it be changed if I want to find the last one or two characters ?

Using below script seems work on the name with hyphen:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=-" %%a in ("%computername%") do (echo "%%a" set Var=%%a)
```

Comment: so what is the problem? you seem to have a solution?

Comment: No, I am looking for solution.

Comment: I meant if there is any script that get the characters from the right instead of from the left. I know I can achieve the result using %computername:~10,2% but if the computer name has different length (some has 10 or 13 characters) then the result is not accurated ! Any help ??